# MDT WDS network boot is very slow

Tags: wds, mdt-2012

Server is running 2008R2 with WDS role enabled. Using MDT 2012 I have created a boot image and imported it into WDS.

Client computers can boot from the WDS and it says "Windows is loading files..." and is very slow loading the \boot\boot.sdi, often taking an hour or more.

The slowness only exhibits on the Toshiba laptop clients. Dell laptops have no issue and boot up within a few seconds. What could be causing this and how can I fix it?

I have imported up to date Atheros drivers for the Toshiba and optimized the boot image.  I have also created a generic boot image with the same result.

Comment: I've experienced this issue on a few computers as well...never found the cause though.  They were older Lenovo desktops.

Comment: Sounds like a driver issue with that particular make and model. If it were anything else like duplex mismatch or CRC errors on the switch or whatever, it seems like it would affect all clients, not just that particular type of laptop. You should be able to inject drivers into the boot image if you're desperate.

Comment: Does the Toshiba laptop have a gigabit NIC or are they old enough to have 100M NICs?

Comment: They have GBNIC  @Ryan Ries, MDT creates a boot image that includes NIC drivers from my driver store which has the latest NIC drivers. Thinking it may have been a bad driver I created a new Deployment Share and did not add any drivers, built a new boot image but with the same result.

Comment: Is the BIOS on the client machine current? (I've resolved many issues by updating to the latest BIOS or device firmware.)

Comment: I would also check and see if the BIOS is updated. that would have been my thought.